# How to keep a web crawler running?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-crawler

I want to write my own web crawler in JS. I am thinking of using a node.js solution such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-crawler

The objective is to have a "crawl" every 10 minutes - so every 10 minutes I want my crawler to fetch data from a website.

I understand that I could write an infinite loop such as:

```
var keeRunning = true;
while (keepRunning) {
  // fetch data and process it every 10 minutes
}
```

This could will work perfectly fine if I have my computer on all the time and I am on the website.

However, if I shut down my computer, I can imagine that it will not work any more. So what kind of solution should I consider to keep a script running all the time, even when the computer is shut down?

Comment: Use a web server perhaps?

Comment: You should consider creating a service managed by your OS

Comment: @Tasos K. how would that work? If I write a page that has a while loop, then it only runs when I visit the page. How can it run even when I am not on it?

Comment: Put a monitor (e.g. Uptime Robot) on that page that will hit it every 10 minutes (or set an interval of your choice).

Comment: as this is a node.js module, isn't it suposed to run on the server, not on the client?

Comment: @nbar I am new to nodejs, have no understanding?

Comment: node.js is designed to have JavaScript on Serverside. While normal Javascript is executed on the client side, node.js takes the roll of a serverside script language (like PHP, Perl)

Comment: What sort of data is it that you want to refresh every 10 minutes? I suspect they will notice you at this frequency, and will IP block you - this is far too frequent. I run scrapers and they operate once a day.

Comment: A simple virtual private server (VPS) is fine here. You can install Node there, and run your scraper from a cron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [CronJobber](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron) for scheduling when to run your script (every x minutes, or at set times, etc) and deploy your app somewhere so it will be hosted on-line on a **server** *that never shuts down*. There are plenty solutions like this where you can host your node server for free

- [C9](http://c9.io)
- [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/)
- [Nodejitsu](https://www.nodejitsu.com/)